# Calendar Gridview - slide in and out animation on month switched

Tags: android, animation, gridview, transition, slide

I want to animate `Gridview` which works as Calendar. 
Calendar items(days, months) are added to gridview dynamicaly on button click, when i choose next or previous month.

I want to create slide in and slide out animation when i change month as uses Viewpager. I can animate slide out and slide in using `listener` and starting slide In `onAnimationEnd()` of slide Out `listener`.

Problem is I want to start both animations on this gridview at the same time(so gridview will be sliding out and in at the same time), but second animation always overide the first animation so i see only slide in animation.

Has anyone any idea how to achieve this kind of animation on gridview?

Thank you